# Debugging Chromecast Receiver App (this device doesn't support the platform API)

Tags: android, chromecast

I have a receiver app. according to the debug panel on port 9222. The console spits out these lines shortly thereafter

```
[  0.162s] [goog.net.WebSocket] An error occurred: undefined
[  0.172s] [cast.receiver.ChannelOverWebSocket] Dispatch ERROR event to ws://localhost:8008/system/control
[  0.177s] [cast.receiver.Channel] Dispatch ERROR event to ws://localhost:8008/system/control
[  0.182s] [cast.receiver.Platform] Platform channel has an error: ws://localhost:8008/system/control
```

Then after a series of these errors (on a retry loop):

```
[  8.335s] [cast.receiver.Platform] This device doesn't support the platform API.
```

Please suggest me where i m going wrong.